# Wrapping an additional element around an existing XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have a converted HTML document, and I wanted to wrap an extra tag around the parent, so that I could read the `head` and `body`. How would I do that with C#? The file is used as an `XDocument`.

change

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- data -->
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- data -->
    </body>
</html>
```

to

```
<open>
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- data -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- data -->
        </body>
   </html>
</open>
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose `doc` is your existing document. Then you just need

```
var wrapped = new XElement("open", doc);
```

and you have an `XElement` with what you want.